# Can a solar cell based lux meter produce useful readings for ultraviolet light?

Tags: led, solar-cell, safety, lighting, light-sensor

I was reading the question [Safety Guidelines for Ultraviolet LEDs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25851/safety-guidelines-for-ultraviolet-leds/25856#25856) about ultraviolet exposure, and realized that a solar cell can probably detect this, since solar cells can also detect visible light, and I am now assuming ultraviolet, because it is higher energy than infrared. For some high producers of ultraviolet, it would be good to have some kind of measurement that can show when the ultraviolet radiation gets to the dangerous level.

I think my understanding of this came from the fact that all digital cameras are actually infrared sensors, but special filters in front of the sensor allows it to then sense color pixels. Carefully removing the filters changes the camera into an infrared camera.

Thanks.

Comment: solar cells and CCDs don't work the same way. you can simply peel off the rubbery pigment layer from a warm white COB LED and stick it onto the opto sensor to convert UV to visible at point of use.

Comment: Silicon sensors will detect UV light, but the packaging around then may not be UV transmissive. What wavelengths are you using? This is going to make a big difference.

Comment: I was thinking the cell or CCD might have to be exposed, because you would want to detect any wavelength, really, but just the ones that are dangerous, and at least 365nm to 410nm.

Comment: Re, "a solar cell can probably detect this, since solar cells can also detect visible light." I don't know the answer to your question, but your logic is flawed. Just because something responds to visible light does not mean that it must also respond to UV light. Your eyes, for example, respond to visible light, but not to UV light.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Okay. "might" or "can hopefully"  instead of "can probably" if you prefer. But I will stick to my first guesstimate of "can probably". Does anybody know, one way or the other?

Comment: @SolomonSlow --   And it's fine with me if the answer is "a solar cell won't work -- you have to use a CCD".